# Charset UTF-8 is not applied when th:include is used

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using the following line of code in my html page

```
<th:block th:replace="modal/bankProfilModal">
     <div></div>
</th:block>
```

**bankProfilModal** has Bootstrap Dialog boxes. It contains no *html, head* or *body* tag.

After the page is loaded, the charset should be applied to all of the dialog boxes but it's not happening. I must mention here that it is a spring boot application and there is no java based or xml based component resolver!

Comment: @All! Before down-voting, keep this in mind that I am bound to use the provided configurations only!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no other solution but added the meta tag in all html files, containing dialog box!